Use of TX/RX on Wemos Relay Shield
I am using this relay shield in a project and I am curious of the use of the TX/RX pins for this component.

There are quite a few pins on this shield when D1 is all that's needed to trigger the latch. There are also I2C and SPI pins so is serial communication possible with this or am I wildly misunderstanding something? I've been having trouble finding a formal datasheet or any other examples using pins other that D1 for operation. Thank you in advance.

The shield simply has the standard names at all its pins coming from the MCU. It does not necessarily mean that there is something connected in the shield. The schematic of, for example, the D1 mini shows that the pins break out the respective signals:

Commonly PCB designers use standard definitions of the parts to place on the board. Apparently in this case, the designer decided to use the predefined part for the shield's connection. And then s/he did not bother to remove the pin labels that are not connected. Yes, we can look at this like a failure.
So you cannot make any use of TX or RX with the relay shield. Its schematic shows that there is no part that can communicate via TX/RX, SPI, or I2C.

This excerpt of the shield's schematic shows that you can change the controlling pin. As delivered, D1 (IO5) is pre-selected:

This 1:1 snippet of the PCB's picture shows the copper trace clearly:

If you want to change the pin, you will cut that trace and solder another one.

Did you look at the internal schematic?  That was on the link you posted.  Here's what it is.  If this is accurate, then it looks like all of the input pins are tied together and just connect to the gate of the MOSFET driver for the relay.  So no microcontroller or anything fancy.
As to your question about the TX/RX pins, I can only guess that they correspond to the NO and NC contacts of the relay.

Overall, this is pretty poor documentation.

They are  not tied together. "SJ" = solder jumper.

So D1 is connected to the gate track?  So then you only need to use D1 to control the gate?

By looking at the link given, D1 is the default pin and others are disconnected, unless the user changes it.

The TX and RX pins also do not correspond to the NO ad NC pins - why would they? The documentation may be poor, but not useless. This is just a relay module that can be bolted on top of some MCU module, one selectable IO pin controlling the relay, plus 5V supply and ground for the relay.

So then why the TX/RX nomenclature?  My rationale - because the relay is used to switch a common path between a transmit (TX) and receive (RX) channel.

Imagine this board being a relay "shield" for an Arduino. There is a pin header with all the pins, the relay board leaves TX/RX and many other pins unconnected, even if they are available from MCU board. The TX and RX are left unused here because the MCU board uses it itself (like Arduino) or it is left unused for more important add-on boards like a modem or RS-485 link.


... I am curious of the use of the TX/RX pins for this component.

The RX/TX pins are not populated. There is no usage of them.

There are also I2C and SPI pins so is serial communication possible with this or am I wildly misunderstanding something?

Technically yes, you could but it would be useless in this application. There's no peripheral device to communicate to.
Microcontrollers typically have multipurpose pins, meaning that it can be configured as GPIO, I2C, SPI, ADC, etc. depending on what the datasheet says.

The relay is triggered by one single pin - but you can select which one by cutting tracks and soldering to select which one you want. These are called solder jumpers.
However the TX and RX are not among selectable pins, they are unused by this relay shield.
And while SPI and I2C pins are among the selectable pins, they are not used as SPI or I2C but simply as an IO pin to control the relay which will prevent the usage of the pin for SPI or I2C if you select one of them for controlling the relay.
Also, even if the relay itself seems to be rated for mains voltage use, the PCB design has relay contact copper tracks too close to the low voltage copper tracks so it is unsafe.
